# dovecot Возможность аутидентификации по сертификату сохраняя при этом парольную

Tags: email, auth, dovecot

Хочу настроить dovecot на аутентификацию smtp, pop, imap по сертификату и паролю, по принципу как в ssh.

Если пользователь передаёт валидный сертификат, отпечаток которого совпадает со списком, например в `/etc/postfix/relay_ccerts` или в дополнительном поле `passdb` из `/etc/dovecot/users`, то он сразу её проходит без пароля, или с любым паролем.
Если сертификата у пользователя нет или он не валидный или его отпечатка у нас нет, то тогда проверяется пароль из `/etc/dovecot/users`.

Столкнулся с проблемой, что `dovecot` проверку сертификата выполняет только при активации `auth_ssl_require_client_cert = yes`.
Но тогда нужно пользователям или присылать и валидный сертификат и правильный пароль, или записывать пользователям пустой пароль, что отменяет парольную аутентификацию.

Можно ли в принципе реализовать задуманное?

Я раньше думал что нет, но наткнулся на https://wiki.dovecot.org/Variables

```
These variables work only in Dovecot-auth:
%k cert "valid" if client had sent a valid client certificate, otherwise empty.
```

Только вот как `%k` использовать с `driver = passwd-file` не понял.
И будет ли генерироваться эта переменная вообще при `auth_ssl_require_client_cert = no` мне тоже не ясно.